# Can this query ever not use Filesort?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a datetime column that I ORDER BY.
Whatever I do, I keep getting "using where; using filesort" from the EXPLAIN.

Is there no way of getting an ORDER BY on datetime columns to NOT use filesort?

The query is very simple and looks like so:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE creator_id = 1 AND user_id != 1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5`

index is on creator_id and user_id I see no reason to put an index on created since it's basically always unique thus would create an index on all items i.e. as big as the table.

edit: I should mention I have tried putting index on created as well, same result.

Comment: how big is this table? like how many rows, typical row width, total table size in MB?

Comment: show us some sample code

Comment: sample code added. the table has between 200,000 and 1,000,000 rows. At this very moment the table has 413,000 rows and is 53 mb in size. It has 8 columns. Nothing unusual i.e. just varchars, datetimes and bigints.

Comment: It's just about impossible to comment sensibly on performance without see 1. Table design, and 2. The EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create compound index on `(creator_id, created)`, your query should work much faster.

Query planner will use first part of the index: `creator_id` to satisfy WHERE constraint, and second part of `created` to sort.

Comment: Thank you. I had index on all three. That didn't make a difference whereas this made a world of difference. If you have a book suggestion where I can learn more about this I'd really appreciate it.